# Creating Supplier Quotation through Supplier Portal in ERPNext

Tags: python, erpnext, frappe

I'm currently working on implementing a supplier portal within ERPNext, and I'm facing a challenge when it comes to allowing suppliers to create quotations directly through the portal. I've set up the portal to enable suppliers to log in and interact with the system, but I'm not entirely sure about the steps required to enable them to submit quotations using ERPNext's DocType functionality.

Could anyone provide guidance on how I can achieve this without relying on API endpoints? Specifically, I'm seeking information on:

Custom DocType: Should I create a custom DocType to handle supplier quotations submitted through the portal? If so, what fields should be included in this DocType to properly capture the quotation details?

Thank you for your valuable assistance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.